# Order by own `position` using sql

Tags: mysql

I have few hundreds items in table with `position is null`, I want to do an order by position and set `position` to `1,2,3,4` and etc, but also live the other results with same `position is null`

the problem is, if I'm ordering `by order by position asc`, first results come where `position is null` and only after them comes results I want to be first. I what that these results with `null` would go in the end.

Is it possible to solve this only with sql?

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN position is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select position
from YourTable
order by case 
when position is null 
then 1 else 0 end, position
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Select position --Your other columns
from yourtable
where position is not null
order by position asc
UNION
Select position --Your other columns
from yourtable
where position is null
```

But be sure to have the same number and names of columns for each select